# How to implement a redirect with HTMX?

Tags: javascript, redirect, htmx

HTMX is great and using AJAX for most of the stuff is awesome! But from time to time I just need a real "phyiscal" redirect to another page.

Any ideas how to achieve this without starting to write custom JS code?

Thx!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Luckily, after googleing for ages I found this post at Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/htmx/comments/ot6kai/comment/h6v5cn9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

You can easily set the `HX-Redirect` header in your backend and on the return of the response, your browser will magically redirect.

The docs state this [here](https://htmx.org/docs/#response-headers) but unfortunately don't explain it in more detail on other pages.

Supplemantal: I experienced an issue with JS errors occuring after the redirect - even though everything works fine.

Comment: I used this **reddit** and it was very useful for me. Only if you are using Django: https://www.reddit.com/r/htmx/comments/s36zx2/how_do_you_use_hxredirect/

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found is to return a meta tag, as it has the ability to refresh the page (or redirect to a new page) after set amount of seconds.

Refresh the page 5 seconds after html loads:

`<div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"></div>`

Redirect to a new page 0 seconds after html loads:

`<div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/new-page/"></div>`

Delaying the page redirect could be useful if you want to show a success animation or something before redirecting.