# How to change HTMX behavior to replace the full web page if form is invalid

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

If this form submits as invalid, I want to override the htmx and do a HttpRedirectResponse that refreshes the full page instead of just changing the div, #superdiv, contents.

```
<form id="create_form" action="." method="post" hx-post="." hx-target="#superdiv" hx swap="outerHTML">
        {{ form }}
        <button id="button" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
```

I have been attempting to do this in the def post of my views.

```
if form.is_valid():
    return self.form_valid(form)
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("logs:manager_form"))
```

Would this be achieved better using JavaScript?  I am trying my best to sticking to learning only vanilla JavaScript for now.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you already use it but the `django-htmx` extension is really good and handy.

You can trigger an entire client refresh from your Django view.

[HttpResponseClientRefresh](https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#django_htmx.http.HttpResponseClientRefresh)

I hope it is useful

Comment: I appreciate the knowledge!  I might have to look at that sometime.

I found the answer on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569673/htmx-hx-target-swap-html-vs-full-page-reload

Comment: But this will not display the error messages of the form, I think.